# Virtual Disk Service (VDS) shuts down every three days on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, dell-perc

Out of many servers all running Server 2008 R2 we have one where the VDS shuts down exactly every three days. The only way to resolve this is to reboot the machine. I have looked in the event logs and nothing ever indicates what might cause the VDS to stop and not restart. I have also tried to restart the service but it fails to restart.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Trace log:

```
(PID:6440,TID:19296,15:16:15.805) INFO: Event logged: 42000003
(PID:6440,TID:19092,15:16:15.805) ERROR: CVdsPnPNotificationBase::NotificationThread, 2, 8
(PID:6440,TID:4248,15:16:15.805) ERROR: CVdsPnPNotificationBase::CreateListenThread: notification thread failed.
(PID:6440,TID:18016,15:16:15.805) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:5460,TID:18848,15:16:15.805) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:6440,TID:19296,15:16:15.805) ERROR: ~CVdsPnPNotificationBase: PostThreadMessage failed: 5A4
(PID:6440,TID:19296,15:16:15.805) INFO: Event logged: 42000004
(PID:17080,TID:19704,15:16:18.878) INFO: Event logged: 42000003
(PID:17080,TID:16748,15:16:18.878) ERROR: CVdsPnPNotificationBase::NotificationThread, 2, 8
(PID:17080,TID:5840,15:16:18.878) ERROR: CVdsPnPNotificationBase::CreateListenThread: notification thread failed.
(PID:17080,TID:17356,15:16:22.575) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:6952,TID:19708,15:16:22.575) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:17080,TID:17356,15:16:37.582) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:6952,TID:19708,15:16:37.582) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:17080,TID:16548,15:16:52.590) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:6952,TID:19708,15:16:52.590) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:17080,TID:17356,15:17:07.597) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:6952,TID:19708,15:17:07.597) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:17080,TID:16548,15:17:22.604) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:6952,TID:19708,15:17:22.604) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:17080,TID:17356,15:25:07.625) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:21388,TID:11100,15:25:07.625) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:17080,TID:19704,15:25:34.566) ERROR: ~CVdsPnPNotificationBase: PostThreadMessage failed: 5A4
(PID:17080,TID:19704,15:25:34.566) INFO: Event logged: 42000004
(PID:19392,TID:14820,15:25:35.908) INFO: Event logged: 42000003
(PID:19392,TID:17812,11:29:32.958) ERROR: CVdsPnPNotificationBase::NotificationThread, 2, 8
(PID:19392,TID:10176,11:29:32.958) ERROR: CVdsPnPNotificationBase::CreateListenThread: notification thread failed.
(PID:19392,TID:13948,11:29:32.958) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:21128,TID:20192,11:29:32.958) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:19392,TID:14820,11:29:32.958) ERROR: ~CVdsPnPNotificationBase: PostThreadMessage failed: 5A4
(PID:19392,TID:14820,11:29:32.958) INFO: Event logged: 42000004
(PID:17728,TID:20668,11:29:37.747) INFO: Event logged: 42000003
(PID:17728,TID:17048,11:29:37.763) ERROR: CVdsPnPNotificationBase::NotificationThread, 2, 8
(PID:17728,TID:10748,11:29:37.763) ERROR: CVdsPnPNotificationBase::CreateListenThread: notification thread failed.
(PID:17728,TID:17892,11:29:41.538) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:12076,TID:19936,11:29:41.538) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
(PID:17728,TID:17892,11:29:56.545) ERROR: CVdsService::Initialize, 1, error=80042401
(PID:12076,TID:19936,11:29:56.545) ERROR: CVdsLoader::LoadService, 5, hr=80042401
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea of the cause, but I suggest you begin your troubleshooting by concentrating on getting the service restarted. You can be sure that whatever prevents it from being restarted will also be causing it to fail in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Could be Shadow Copy Components or System State backup that is causing this. Check all schedule tasks and backups

Also could you post a section of the event log showing the event? and explain wath this server does?